# How do I change website background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've made a quiz which has 10 questions, and stores your points in a value called `total`. The total points you are able to get is 20, so when `total > 10`, I want the background to turn **red**.

I have already set a background using CSS on my website here:

```
<style type="text/css">
    body{
    background-image: url("twins.jpg");
}
```

However I can't seem to get my condition to work properly. I've tried:

```
if (total > 10) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
    }
```

I've tried:

```
if (total > 10) {
        document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
    }
```

And:

```
if (total > 10) {
        document.getElementById('body').style.backgroundImage = "url(ashishot.jpg)";
    }
```

But nothing seems to work. Maybe I'm placing my `if` statement in the wrong place, or maybe I'm trying to set the background incorrectly, I just want to know if this is the correct way to change a background image from CSS into JavaScript.

Comment: is it entering your if loop?

Comment: your code is correct, it only depends when you execute it. Like dkengaroo said, you need to test this as soon as you increment the total (after each question answer)

Comment: obviously wherever you make this check `total` value do not exceed 10. Do you have more than one `total` variable to conflict. Also keep in mind that the DOM elements can be directly referenced by their ids in the window scope. So if you have an element with `id="total"` it might create confusion.

Comment: You should remove background image if want background color over it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is the correct way to change background color using JS.

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000";
```

Please try:

- Placing `alert()` inside the IF block to see if block is executing
- See if something is overlayed(z-indexed) on body

Answer (score 0):

The javascript instruction is correct

```
document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red";
```

Your error may be the if condition, check if total its work properly usign the console or an alert to check it:

```
console.log(total);
```

or

```
alert(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have more than one issue

1. Use directly the `body` property

   ```
   document.body.style.backgroundImage
   ```
2. You need to quote the whole assignment and you need inner quotes for the image

   ```
   'url("ashishot.jpg")';
   ```

Working example:

```js
function setBackground() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = 'url("http://lorempixel.com/300/200/")';
}
setTimeout(setBackground, 2000);
```

```css
body {
    background-image: url("http://lorempixel.com/400/200/");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (total > 10) {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url(ashishot.jpg)";
}
```

`body` is not an id. also, setting `background-color` will not work because browser treat `background-image` first. To display `background-color` instead of `background-image`, simply delete the image. Setting classes is more flexible.

```js
document.body.classList.add("total");
```

```css
body {
  background-image: url("http://www.studiocity-macau.com/uploads/images/SC/Entertainment/Batman/batman_share.jpg");
}

body.total {
  background-image: none;
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Be aware that your `backgound-image` will be on top of the color you are setting in the `if` block. If the image covers the background entirely you will not notice the effect of changing the `background color`.

Both `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "#AA0000"` and `document.body.style.backgroundColor = "red"` are valid (although `"red" == "#FF0000"`).

Make sure the `if` statement runs every time `total` increases.